# keep getting this error "Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, gemfile, snap

I have installed the latest release of ruby with "Sudo snap install ruby --classic" and i have confirmed with "which ruby" and "ruby -v" commands that the ruby exists and that the latest version ruby 3.2.2 also exists but whenever i tyried to run my rails app on the server i get this error "Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.2"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your Ruby version is changing to 3.0.2 when you navigate to your Rails application repository or folder, you can try the following steps to potentially resolve the problem:

1. Install RVM (Ruby Version Manager).
2. Check if your preferred Ruby version is already installed using the
   command "*rvm list*".
3. If your Ruby version is not installed, install it by running the
   command "*rvm install 3.2.2*" (replace "3.2.2" with your desired
   version).
4. Set the Ruby version to be used by running the command "*rvm use
   3.2.2*".
5. give "*bundle i*"

OR

1. Use the command "*rvm --create --ruby-version 3.2.2*" to create the
   .ruby-version file for automatic selection of the Ruby version.
2. give "*bundle install*" command

Note: delete Gemfile.lock file before giving bundle install